# Power Query: Average, Max, Min, Count using filters and conditions between tables

Tags: excel, filter, powerbi, powerquery

I’m new to Power Query and have gotten stuck for the last few weeks trying to figure this out. I have two tables...

1. Historical_Data_Table (contains all my historical datapoints that I want to filter to determine different prices):

| DATE | Cloud% | Wind_KM | Solar_Utiliz | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan | 0.85 | 0 | 0.1 | 4.5 |
| 02-Jan | 0.85 | 0 | 0.1 | 4.5 |
| 03-Jan | 0.95 | 15 | 0 | 10 |
| 04-Jan | 0.95 | 15 | 0 | 8 |
| 05-Jan | 0.6 | 25 | 0.35 | 6 |
| 06-Jan | 0.6 | 25 | 0.35 | 6 |
| 07-Jan | 0.2 | 55 | 0.8 | 6 |
| 08-Jan | 0.2 | 55 | 0.8 | 7 |
| 09-Jan | 0.55 | 10 | 0.5 | 5.5 |
| 10-Jan | 0.55 | 10 | 0.5 | 5.5 |
| 11-Jan | 0.28 | 12 | 0.6 | 2 |
| 12-Jan | 0.28 | 12 | 0.6 | 2 |
| 13-Jan | 0.1 | 40 | 0.9 | 3 |
| 14-Jan | 0.1 | 40 | 0.9 | 3 |
| 15-Jan | 0.33 | 17 | 0.7 | 8 |
| 16-Jan | 0.01 | 17 | 0.95 | 1 |
| 17-Jan | 0.01 | 17 | 0.95 | 1 |

2. Forecast_Tbl (contains my weather forecasts and 3 buckets composed of Max and Min Requirments):

| Date | Fcst_Cloud | Fcst_Wind | Fcst_Solar | Max_Cloud | Min_Cloud | Max_Wind | Min_Wind | Max_Solar | Min_Solar | Count | Min | Max | Mode | Median | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 12 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 0.3 | 27 | -3 | 0.75 | 0.25 | 5 | 5.5 | 8 | 6 | 6 | 6.2 |
| 2 | 0.8 | 10 | 0.1 | 1 | 0.6 | 25 | -5 | 0.35 | -0.15 | 6 | 4.5 | 10 | 4.5 | 6 | 6.5 |
| 3 | 0.15 | 15 | 0.8 | 0.35 | -0.05 | 30 | 0 | 1.05 | 0.55 | 5 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 2 | 2.8 |

This is where I've gotten stumped. I want to add **6 additional columns** COUNT, MIN, MAX, MODE, MEDIAN, AVERAGE (**The Forecast_Tbl above INCLUDES these 6 columns (Count:Average) and expected outputs for illustration)**

The filter criteria for calculating the count, min, max, mode, median, and average are driven by the 6 different min/max columns in "forecast_tbl" as filters for looking up the historical_data_table points and the corresponding Historical_Data_Table[Price].

It will do this for each row in my forecast_tbl (essentially each row in the Forecast_tbl is a different price forecast).

For example, for Date "1" in Forecast_Tbl, The “count” column tells me it's found 5 price points in the "Historical_data_table” that satisfied my 6 criteria:

1. (Historical_Data_Table[Cloud%]<=.70)
2. (Historical_Data_Table[Cloud%]>=.30)
3. (Historical_Data_Table[Wind_KM]<=27)
4. (Historical_Data_Table[Wind_KM]>=-3)
5. (Historical_Data_Table[Solar_Utiliz]<=.75)
6. (Historical_Data_Table[Solar_Utiliz]>=.25)

Based on those same criteria it found a MIN price of $5.50, MAX price of $8.00, MODE and MEDIAN of $6.00, and AVERAGE price of $6.20, based on those 5 historical price data points. (see my COUNT/FILTER formula in picture below)
[Excel Count/Filter Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co7Ig.png)

For Date "2" in Forecast_Tbl, The “count” column tells me it's found 6 price points in the "Historical_data_table” that satisfied my 6 different criteria. Based on those same criteria it found a “min” price of $4.50, max price of $10.00, mode of 4.5 and median of $6.00, and average price of $6.50, based on those 6 price points.

The following are my six dynamic filtering criteria:

1.Historical_Data_Table[cloud%] <= Forecast_tbl[max cloud]

2.Historical_Data_Table[cloud%] >= Forecast_tbl[min cloud]

3.Historical_Data_Table[Wind_km] <= Forecast_tbl[max wind]

4.Historical_Data_Table[Wind_km] >= Forecast_tbl[min wind]

5.Historical_Data_Table[SolarUtiliz] <= Forecast_tbl[max solar]

6.Historical_Data_Table[SolarUtiliz] >= Forecast_tbl[min solar]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have tried using different filters and lookups in Power Query but haven't been successful.

I have tried using Average, Min, Max, with Filters embedded but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: I can't believe that a new contributor just wrote this !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns a table with the aggregations appended to your Forecast table.

However, each of the filtered tables has two Modes. I chose to return the "First" in the list that was generated since that seems to agree with what you show, but you might want to handle the Mode calculation differently.

Also note that this may take quite a while to work on a large set of historical data. A filtered table has to be generated for each row in the Forecast table, and that can take a while as the entire DB needs to be examined. I added some `Table.Buffer` functions which may help a bit.

The `List.Generate` function initially generates a list of filtered tables, corresponding to each row in the Forecast table. But in the last argument of the function, we process that table to generate Records of the desired aggregations, which we will subsequently combine with the original rows in the Forecast table.

***Edit to simplify code a bit***

```
let

//Read in Historical table and set data types
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Historical"]}[Content],
    Historical = Table.Buffer(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"DATE", type date}, {"Cloud%", type number}, {"Wind_KM", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Solar_Utiliz", type number}, {"Price", type number}})),

//Read in Forecast table anda set data types
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Forecast"]}[Content],
    Forecast = Table.Buffer(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{
        {"Date", Int64.Type}, {"Fcst_Cloud", type number}, {"Fcst_Wind", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Fcst_Solar", type number}, {"Max_Cloud", type number}, 
        {"Min_Cloud", type number}, {"Max_Wind", Int64.Type}, {"Min_Wind", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Max_Solar", type number}, {"Min_Solar", type number}})),

//Generate list of filtered Historical Table for each row in Forecast Table with aggregations
//Merge aggregations with the associated Forecast row
    #"Filtered Historical" = List.Generate(
        ()=>[t=Table.SelectRows(Historical, (h)=> 
                    h[#"Cloud%"] <= Forecast[Max_Cloud]{0} and h[#"Cloud%"]>= Forecast[Min_Cloud]{0}
                and h[Wind_KM] <= Forecast[Max_Wind]{0} and h[Wind_KM] >= Forecast[Min_Wind]{0}
                and h[Solar_Utiliz] <= Forecast[Max_Solar]{0} and h[Solar_Utiliz] >= Forecast[Min_Solar]{0}),
                idx=0],
            each [idx] < Table.RowCount(Forecast),
            each [t=Table.SelectRows(Historical, (h)=> 
                    h[#"Cloud%"] <= Forecast[Max_Cloud]{[idx]+1} and h[#"Cloud%"]>= Forecast[Min_Cloud]{[idx]+1}
                and h[Wind_KM] <= Forecast[Max_Wind]{[idx]+1} and h[Wind_KM] >= Forecast[Min_Wind]{[idx]+1}
                and h[Solar_Utiliz] <= Forecast[Max_Solar]{[idx]+1} and h[Solar_Utiliz] >= Forecast[Min_Solar]{[idx]+1}),
                idx=[idx]+1],
            each Forecast{[idx]} & Record.FromList(
                {List.Count([t][Price]),List.Min([t][Price]), List.Max([t][Price]),
                  List.Modes([t][Price]){0}, List.Median([t][Price]), List.Average([t][Price])}, 
                    {"Count","Min","Max","Mode","Median","Average"})),

    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Filtered Historical", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", 
        {"Date", "Fcst_Cloud", "Fcst_Wind", "Fcst_Solar", "Max_Cloud", "Min_Cloud", "Max_Wind", "Min_Wind", "Max_Solar", "Min_Solar", 
            "Count", "Min", "Max", "Mode", "Median", "Average"}),
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{
        {"Date", Int64.Type}, {"Fcst_Cloud", Percentage.Type}, {"Fcst_Wind", Int64.Type}, {"Fcst_Solar", type number}, 
        {"Max_Cloud", type number}, {"Min_Cloud", type number}, {"Max_Wind", Int64.Type}, {"Min_Wind", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Max_Solar", type number}, {"Min_Solar", type number}, {"Count", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Min", Currency.Type}, {"Max", Currency.Type}, {"Mode", Currency.Type}, {"Median", Currency.Type}, {"Average", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

***Output from your Data***
[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you! I just ran it in PQ and it's perfect! What is the "Price" column in the Output data (between Solar_Utiliz and Count)? Is that the 2nd Mode you mentioned?

Comment: Perfect, I see that now, and it removed the "Price" column that was showing up! Thank you!

Comment: @Joel There are still two `Modes` in your Price column. I am only returning one of them (the first) as that is what you show in your example using `List.Modes([t][Price]){0}`, but if you want to handle lists with more than one mode some other way, you should specify.

Comment: Thank you, that mode it returns is good for now, I will investigate further.
I have another question tied to this. Suppose my “Forecast_Table” was just one row – Date “1” for example, when I run this query I want the output to be the Filtered “Historical_Data_Table” so that I can view the 5 different rows (from the historical_data_Table” that make up my calculated columns in the Forecast table. It would look like this:

Comment: | DATE | Cloud% | Wind_KM | Solar_Utiliz | Price |
| - | - | - | - | - |
| 44931 | 0.6 | 25 | 0.35 | 6 |
| 44932 | 0.6 | 25 | 0.35 | 6 |
| 44935 | 0.55 | 10 | 0.5 | 5.5 |
| 44936 | 0.55 | 10 | 0.5 | 5.5 |
| 44941 | 0.33 | 17 | 0.7 | 8 |

Comment: @Joel That's a different question. But you would start by changing the last argument of the `#"Filtered Historical"` step from calculating all the aggregations to just `each [t]` which would return the filtered table. You would then just expand that table. Or you could add it in that last step as another column, and then you could have the aggregations appended also.

Comment: appreciate all your help with this! I'll work on that last step myself and see how far I can get. Thank you again.